# Lists of lists with paths a flight can take and distance?

Tags: prolog

So, I am trying to learn Prolog as a recommendation of a friend in my beginning AI journey, its getting very hard and i cant find any similar solution here at stack, so i decided to ask, im working with a list of lists, this lists saves the plane flights that are available at a city airport, going from X to Y , with a defined distance, my knowledge base looks something like this:

```
airports([culiacan,mazatlan,chihuahua,guadalajara,df]).

flightdistance([[culiacan,mazatlan,5],[culiacan,chihuahua,6],[mazatlan,chihuahua,5],
                [mazatlan,guadalajara,7],[chihuahua,culiacan,6],[chihuahua,guadalajara,8],
                [chihuahua,df,9],[guadalajara,culiacan,10],[guadalajara,df,3],
                [df,chihuahua,9],[df,guadalajara,3]]).
```

As you see, in my second list, "flightdistance" ,each list inside of it has the departure airport, then the destination, and finally the distance that will be traveled, not all airports have a direct flight to one another, so they have to take scales in order to arrive, right now, i need an idea, im lost, the only thing i´ve been able to achieve is knowing if a determined city can get directly to another city, something like the base case:

```
flight(X,Y):-directpath(X,Y).

flightR(X,Y,[[X,Y,_]|_]).
flightR(X,Y,[_|LL]):-flightR(X,Y,LL).

directpath(X,Y):-flightdistance(Z),flightR(X,Y,Z).
```

Im really lost, i think i just made a mess and dont know how to fix it, like i said, i need to know what paths can take me from X to Y and what distance will be traveled, i´ve tried to follow the same structure that some directed graph examples show here at stackoverflow, but i havent been able to translate that to work with lists, any idea will be much appreciate it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Writing your data as a single fact that is a list of lists is actually a poor way to represent the facts. That's one reason you're finding other questions and answers that don't do it that way. My advice is to use individual facts: `flight(culiacan,mazatlan,5).` for example. It will make your code simpler, and many of the other Q&A on stack overflow you've found will start to apply. It allows you to write simple queries such as, `flight(From, To, Distance), Distance < 8` to find all of the flights with distance less than 8.

Comment: @lurker Oh my, thank you, god, i have all weekend trying to solve it that way, thanks a lot, i dont know why i kept trying that way, maybe because thats the example they gave me, but you just clarify everything for me, now i notice how everything would have been easier since the beggining-